# phpdoc @var in php file

Tags: php, eclipse, autocomplete, ide, phpdoc

i have next php code

```
<?php
class A {
    public function foo() {

    }
}
/**
 * @var A $a
 */
$a->
```

I want to make my ide autocomplete $a-> correct, and show me that there is only one available method foo in $a. There is no any string like $a = new A();
$a instantiated in another place and handled by autoloader.

Comment: this probably depends highly on which IDE you're using.

Comment: it should depend on phpdoc. if phpdoc support it it should work in every ide, which uses phpdoc

Comment: @Rus I don't think *this* will work. What might have a chance to work is to get phpDoc to include the autoloader file first - that is possible in many IDEs but I have no idea whether it's possible in phpDoc itself

Comment: @Pekka, IDE can't calculate a runtime workflow of autoloader. it must be based on static phpdoc syntax.

Comment: @Rus many IDEs allow the addition of include files to parse for the purpose of documentation. You might be able to go that way

Comment: @Pekka, but autoload is runtime workflow. Thanks for your opinion.

Comment: @Rus but so what if it is? What speaks against adding the autoloaded file manually to the documentation parser's scope? It would be a cleaner way than overriding the variable's meaning elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following syntax works fine in eclipse

```
/* @var $a A */
$a->
```

Note that I switched parameters order.

Comment: i see, which version of eclipse do you use ? in my eclipse 
Version: 3.7.0
Build id: I20110613-1736
it doesn't work.

Comment: I've just edited my answer. This syntax should works. I've tested it in eclipse helios 3.6.

Comment: note the whitespaces at begging and end are important for eclipse

Answer (score 0):

For some reason PDT in Eclipse swaps the order of the @var parameters. This syntax works:

```
<?php
class A {
    public function foo() {

    }
}
/**
 * @var $a A
 */
$a->
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a variant of eloquent that autopopulates variables and the autohinting utterly fails in my eclipse, wether I place it above, under it, single line, multi line comments.

I did find a way in which it does work for me.

```
class Foo extends Model {
    public function beforeSave() {
        $bar = $this->bar;
        foreach($bar as $baz) {
            $baz-> // <-- this works now \o/
        }
    }
    /**
     * @return \Foo\Baz\Models\Bar
     */
    public function getBar() {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}
```